# how do i check if the session is going to expire in php

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a usecase that i want to check if the session is going to expire in 30 sec or 60 sec. if so I should be able to extend the session. I am fine with any solutions with session or cookies. How do I acomplish that. Pls eloborate your solution. But I should know before the session expires.

Answer (score 0):

php.ini sets a sesion_maxlifetime but this is not reliable because a session could last longer, depending on when the garbage collector in PHP is called.

I recommend storing your session metadata in a database with a column to specify the expiry time (you could use `datetime` quite well). Once a user calls a page with `session_start()`, you can take the `$_COOKIE['my_cookie_name]` value and use a library like `mysqli` to fetch the expiry time. You may want to then store this as a session variable too, as well as in the database, so you don't have to make database calls all the time to get the session expiry, e.g. `$_SESSION['expiry'] = time() + 60*60*24*365` for a session that'll expire in 356 days.

You can then do a `session_unset()` with a `session_destroy()` function call to clean your session when validating the user request.

Actual session data can also be stored in a database but you should consider using a key-value store like Redis to make this smoother: doing a lot of database calls on volatile data like sessions might not be the best practice and could create unnecessary load on your servers, especially with many users.